# Binary Search Tree Remove Method

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am making a binary search tree which is sorted by String key. Each node consists of an unordered linked list of information that is associated to a key. The tree is inorder (alphabetical).

I have completed most of the program, but having trouble with the remove method.

Essentially it has to be recursive. The method has to remove a node that has the given key, such that if "Architecture" was the String given, I must traverse through the tree and remove the corresponding node with "Architecture" as its key.

I am having trouble because I have to remove a String. Other assignments have used integers where I have to remove the highest or lowest value. However, I am not removing a node with the highest or lowest String value, but a node that equals to a specified String.

All I'm asking is how to go about this method. You don't have to provide any actual code if you choose not to, but some pointers or advise would be nice.

Thank you.

```
//My attempt:
//Removes node with corresponding k
public void remove(String k) {
    rootNode = remove(rootNode, k);
}

//Recursive method:
private KeyNode remove(KeyNode x, String k) {
    if (x == null) {
        return x;
    }
    //int comparison with compareTo
    //if less than 0, left node = remove(left node, k)
    //if greater than 0, right node = remove(right node, k)
    //if left node and right node are both null, return null
    //if left node is null, return left node
    //if right node is null, return right node
    //return
}
```

Comment: Is your issue with testing string equality in the remove method? If that's the case then use `String.equals`.

Comment: Can you show what your `Node` structure looks like, and provide a simple sample tree containing a node that you want removing?

Comment: your comments in the remove method are essentially correct. You can use compareTo with strings just as easily as integers.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
public rootNode remove (String k, rootNode n) {
    if (n == null)
        return null;

    if (k.compareTo(n.key)<0)
        remove (k, n.leftChild);
    else if (k.compareTo(n.key)>0)
        remove (k, n.rightChild);
    else {
        if (n.leftChild != null && n.rightChild != null)    {
            /* n has two children, find max from left then 
             * switch it with n and remove n */

        }
        else if(n.leftChild != null) {
            /* n has a left child only then left child replaces n 
             * and n is deleted */


        }
        else if(n.rightChild != null) {
            /* n has a right child only then right child replaces n
             * and n is deleted*/

        }
        else {
            n = null;
        }
    }

}
```